# ¿Como muestro los datos en HTML y PHP de dos arreglos JSON?

Tags: php, html, mysql, json

Mi código es el siguiente, tengo 2 consultas, en una tomo las "preguntas" y en la siguiente tomo las "opciones" de la pregunta, solo que no sé como mostrar las opciones que corresponden a la pregunta, debo mostrarlas en un *INPUT* *RADIO*, sé que puedo utilizar un *FOREACH* pero sigo intentándolo. 
Imprimiendo el arreglo de salida me muestra todos los datos correctos, los que necesito, pero cómo mostrarlos en un formulario.
Espero que me puedan ayudar

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET["examen_curso"])) 
{
    $curso_id = $_GET['examen_curso'];

    // echo $curso_id;
    $salida = array();

    $sql = "SELECT cursos.no_preguntas FROM cursos WHERE curso_id= '$curso_id' LIMIT 1";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

    $random = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado);

     // echo $random[0];

    $sql2 = "select * from preguntas where curso_id = '$curso_id' order by rand() limit ".$random[0];

    $res = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql2);

    if($res == false)
        {

            return false;
        }

     while ($r = $res->fetch_assoc()) 
     {
        $sql3 = "select * from opciones where preg_id=".$r['id'];
        $res2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql3);

        $op = array();

        while($r2 = $res2->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $op[] = $r2;
            json_encode($r2);
            // echo "<br>";
        }

        $salida[] = array(
            'id'       => $r['id'],  
            'curso'    => $r['curso_id'],
            'pregunta' => $r['pregunta'],
            'opciones' => $op
        );
     }
     json_encode($salida, true);
}
```

?>

De esta manera muestro solo las preguntas:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="preguntas">

        <div class="divOpciones" class="form-check"> <br>

            <?php foreach ($salida as $ver): ?>

            <input type="hidden" name="pregunta[]" id="pregunta" value="<?php echo $ver['id'];?>">

            <h3><?php echo $ver['pregunta'];?></h3>

            <hr>
            <?php endforeach ?>


        </div>    

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `echo json_encode( $salida, true )` Ya intentaste eso? No tienes normalizada tu base? Se me hacen muchas consultas para lo que pretendes hacer.

Comment: Ya intenté eso y me funciona bien, pero quiero mostrar lel resultado de la consulta en un formulario.

Comment: Cuál resultado? Cuál consulta?

Comment: Me refiero a que el arreglo de salida está bien, obtengo todos los datos necesarios, pero para mostrarlos en forma de cuestionario, la pregunta con sus respectivas opciones.

Comment: Entonces eso no tiene nada que ver con el back.end. Agrega el código del front, tanto el HTML como el Javascript.

Comment: No necesitas una salida tipo JSON, puedes armar ahí la vista y sólo renderizarla. O si es asíncrono, basate en la respuesta de Juan Carlos Hdz

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de ajax o simplemente recorrer el objeto json  e imprimir los datos en etiquetas html

Ejemplo:
si usas ajax

```
$.ajax({
    data:  {}, //send data via AJAX
    url:   'script.php', 
    dataType: "json", 
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type:  'post', //send POST data

    success:  function (response) { //get request   
    $.each(response, function( index, preguntas )
           $("#pregunta").html(preguntas.pregunta)
          $.each(preguntas.opciones, function( i, value ) {
            $("#opciones").appened('<input type="radio" name="option[]" value='+index+'>value<br>')
          });
       });

    }
});
```

en html

```
<div>
  <p id="pregunta"></p>
  <p id="opciones"></p>
</div>
```

se requiere agregar jquery